# Songs are not playing due to Special character in url of the song

Tags: android

I am working in android. I am designing a music player which is playing songs from the server.

When the URL does not has any special character, the song plays well. But when there 
are some special characters in the URL then the song does not play. For example, the following url is not working:

```
http://192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/Songs/desert rose sting & enigma.mp3
```

i am using this code to play my song.

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songURL);

mediaPlayer.prepare();

mediaPlayer.start();
```

i have solved my problem related to the space. please tell me the solution for '&' symbol.

Comment: URL Encoder/Decoder problem? I believe this line is unnecessary songURL=str.replaceAll(" ","%20");

Comment: Rudy sir this line is necessary. Without this line the url which has space does not run. so this is necessary. take care...

Comment: You should use URLEncoder like Harald suggests. Don't create your own encoder.

Comment: the correct encoded URL should be : http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.214%2FMusicApplication%2FSongs%2FMatt%20Cardle%20-%20When%20We%20Collide.mp3, however your own encoder gives http://192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/Songs/Matt%20Cardle%20-%20When%20We%20Collide.mp3

Answer (score 0):

Use URLEncoder.encode(songUrl, "UTF-8");

Comment: As an alternative you could try the following: URI uri = new URI(songUrl); mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri.toASCIIString());